# Stuck on integration question

Tags: integration

The curve in the picture shown has equation $y=bx(x-2)$

[image: curve picture]

(a) Find b given that the shaded area is 4 units$^2$

(b) Find the x-coordinate of the point A if the line OA divides the shaded area into equal parts.

I'm really not sure where to start on this one..any pointers would be great!

My attempt at part (a)

Integrate $y(x)$ between o and 2 and solve for $b$

$y(x)=\int_0^2 bx(x-2)dx=4$

$={b(x-3)x^2\over3}+c$

$=-{4b\over3}$

$b=-3$

for part b, would the integral be:

$\int_0^c [6x-3x^2]-[6-3c]dx=2$

Comment: Do you know how to solve a definite integral? If you can, then why do you struggle with part one? Explain what's difficult for you.

Comment: (a) Integrate y(x) between 0 and 2. (b) The sum of the area under OA (triangle) + the integral of y(x) between the xA and 2 equals 2. This gives you an equation.

Comment: For (a), find the value of $ \ b \ $ so that $ \ \int_0^2 \ \ b \ x \ (x - 2 ) \ \ dx \ = \ 4 \ $ .  For (b), there is a straight line $ \ y \ = \ mx \ $ (since it passes through the origin), that also passes through the point on the parabola $ \ ( c, \ bc (c-2) ) \ $ so that the area from the line "up" to the parabola is half the total of 4 square units, or 2 .  You will use the value of  $ \ b \ $ you found for part (a).

Comment: I'll mention, after working it through, that the value of $ \ b \ $ is a small negative integer.  As dreadful as part (b) _may_ sound, writing the expression for the difference between the function for the parabola and the function for the straight line leads to a helpful cancelation; the $ \ x-$ coordinate of point $ \ A \ $ is the cube-root of a small integer.

Comment: Part (a) looks to be correct.

Comment: Since you have $ \ b \ $ now, we can say a little more about the second part. The point $ \ A \ $ is at an unknown position $ \ ( \ c, \ -3c(c-2) \ ) \ $ , so the line $ \ OA \ $ dividing the parabola has slope $ \ \frac{6c - 3c^2}{c} \ $ .  We want to find the area below the parabola $ \ 6x - 3x^2 \ $ and above the line $ \ (6 - 3c) \ x \ $ between $ \ x = 0 \ $ and $ \ x = c \ $ , obtaining an expression in $ \ c \ $ for the area, which we want to equal $ \ 2 \ $ .   You should get a simple equation for the value of $ \ c \ $ , which will be an irrational number.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not seeing it. Might sacrifice this question

Comment: Have you covered the topic of finding the area between two curves?  That is what is called for here.  You would set up $$ \int_0^c \ \ [6x \ - \ 3x^2 ] \ - \ [ \ (6 - 3c) \ x \ ] \ \ dx \ = \ 2 \ \ . $$  (You are integrating infinitesimal vertical "strips" of area from the parabola "down" to the line from the intersection point of the curves at the origin to the intersection point $ \ A \ $ .)  The value of  $ \ c \ $ is the $ \ x-$ coordinate you are seeking in the second part.

Comment: ok so I end up with $2=-{x^2(2x-3c)\over 2}+c$ The x-coordinate is 1.59 This is high school level mathematics?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this is a high-school calculus course, though I think "area between two curves" is usually in the list of topics.  And yes, the exact result is $ \ c \ = \ \sqrt[3]{4} \ \approx \ 1.58740 \ $ .

Answer (score 1):

(a) Integrate $y(x)$ with respect to $x$ and set this equal to 4. Solve for $b$.

(b) Write an equation of the line passing through point $A$. Set up an integral from $0$ to $A$ under that line and from $A$ to 2 under the given curve. Set this equal to the area above the line (and under the curve; another integral)

Comment: Just use the half below the parabola but above the line to find half the total area.  Then you only need one integration, instead of two to handle the "break" between the bounding line and the $ \ x-$ axis, then between the _parabola_ and the $ \ x-$ axis.